# Shell script to change user, specify some input but then interact with the shell

Tags: shell, ksh, expect

I am writing script to change user from root to `poletst` (another user ). When I change user server ask me among three areas from which I have to select by pressing 1,2 or 3

I am writing a shell script to automate some step and there is a step which involve changing user and selecting area 1 by default.

```
su - poletst
1
```

It is not working. It takes me to the user but doesn't change the area. How to perform this?

Comment: what does that prompt look like?

Comment: the prompt offer me three choices
1) Test
2) Test1
3) Test2
 which can be selected by suing 1 2 or 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
expect -c 'spawn su - poletst; send "1\r"; interact'
```

Or if it doesn't work, try this:

```
expect -c 'spawn su - poletst; expect "prompt"; send "1\r"; interact'
```

Just replace `prompt` with one of the strings in the last line of the message that is shown to you when you're being asked for the area.

You can as well place it as a script

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect -f
spawn su - poletst
expect "prompt"
send "1\r"
interact
```

Save it to a file like `su-poletst.exp` and just run `expect -f su-poletst.exp`.